# Shhh... b(e) quiet

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

j10 x2 d7 s2 m5 a3 s8 z5 (a1 = l, a2 = i)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from @Techidiot’s answer...

> The thumbnail seen in the top half of the puzzle image is from the Vsauce video [Dord.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb0YoRMXIY0) If we go to the time stamp 5:30, as indicated by the bottom half of the puzzle image, we can obtain the following chart:
>  [image: A chart of 26 words, labeled A-Z, each containing that silent letter]

Then...

> We can use the letters and numbers given in the puzzle. For each letter-number pair, we can take the word associated with the letter, and index into it by the number. Doing so gives the final answer of **LAMINATE**. This answer is fitting because the first syllable, “LAM”, is a homophone of “LAMB”, a word which has a silent “B” as indicated in the puzzle’s title.

Comment: Great job finding that :)

Comment: Yep that’s correct

Answer (score 3):

*Super partial -*

> Since it has been 7hrs already. I'll just post what I found. Using [Aperi'Solve](https://www.aperisolve.com/920499261591b44e931c1e04ec2f1ea0) we can see that there's a hidden image inside which shows "Language" and "5:30" in the bottom.
>  [image]
>  For now, that's all I can find. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but seven hours really isn't very long... There will be parts of the world where people have been asleep throughout and won't even have had the chance to see this yet!

Comment: @Stiv Yep. It's just me then haha. And no problems with downvotes :) Also Good Day & have a great Sunday.

Comment: Hi! i'm the creator of this post, here's a little hint to pass the time: V

Comment: @poco Surely someone V :)